# Sending logs Cloudwatch from application running on Windows Server EC2 - log in multiple files/folders

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

We have an application (off the shelf, with a time-based and feature-based licence key) running on a `Windows Server EC2` instance. This application creates logs which are stored in the following directory: `C:\ProgramData\MyApp\v4\Logs`. In this folder, there are many files with names that are `{guid}.txt`.

We want to feed these to `Cloudwatch`. We created the `config.json` but I wanted to ask:

Does the `file_path` in the `config.json` **have to** be pointing to one and only one file? Is it possible to point to a folder?

```
{
  "logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
      "files": {
        "collect_list": [
          {
            "file_path": "C:\\ProgramData\\MyApp\\v4\\Logs\\logs.txt",
            "log_group_name": "Logs-Myapp",
            "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}-Myapp",
            "retention_in_days": 180
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried pointing to a folder but I am not getting any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *file_path* inside the *collect_list* can only point to files. However it does allow for wildards inside the file name to select a range of files. So if your files are always named as {guid}.txt you can use the following pattern.

```
{
    "logs": {
            "logs_collected": {
                    "files": {
                            "collect_list": [
                                    {
                                            "file_path": "C:\\ProgramData\\MyApp\\v4\\Logs\\*.txt",
                                            "log_group_name": "Logs-Myapp",
                                            "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}-Myapp",
                                            "retention_in_days": 180
                                    }
                            ]
                    }
            }
    }
```

}

The [official AWS documentation page for  the logging section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Logssection) of the cloud watch agent also describes that you can use a super asterisk (**) within file paths. In theory that could mean that you can also try the following pattern:

```
"file_path": "C:\\ProgramData\\MyApp\\v4\\Logs\\**"
```

However, I’ve never tried that and the pattern might be a bit too permissive.

Comment: Thank you - Works! I should have rtfm :)

Answer (score 0):

I had exact usecase in the past and I could solve this usecase with the below configuration

```
            {
                "file_path": "C:\\Program Files\\yourFile\\logs\\*",
                "log_group_class": "STANDARD",
                "log_group_name": "YourLGName",
                "log_stream_name": "StreamName",
                "retention_in_days": 5
            }
```

Hope this helps